# Changed iOS App name using InfoPlist localisation

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, info-plist, cfbundledisplayname

I want to change the app name irrespective of the target name because each time I need to change the app name I have to change the target name and I need to do `pod install` so I found a solution i.e. change the `Product Name` under `Packaging`.

I have localized app names in my `InfoPlist.strings`, so If I change the `Product Name` under `Packaging` the system doesn't take app name from `InfoPlist.strings` file.

I tried something like this `$(CFBundleDisplayName)`
, how do I solve this issue?
[image]

Comment: You could create your own custom variable for it in Build Settings > User-Defined.

Comment: @l'L'l how do I point the User-Defined Setting to InfoPlist.strings to take the localized app name?

Comment: Actually `CFBundleDisplayName` should work. How are you setting it in your `InfoPlist.strings` file?

Comment: "CFBundleDisplayName" = "Apple it";
"CFBundleName" = "Apple it";

Comment: @l'L'l `CFBundleDisplayName` works when I keep the `Product Name` as `$(TARGET_NAME)` but the problem is I don't want to keep the `Product Name` as `$(TARGET_NAME)`

Comment: The first one looks like the correct way to set it; when you set  `$(CFBundleDisplayName)` under product name what result do you get?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170410/discussion-between-anirudha-mahale-and-lll).

Comment: Are you able to add Target Name $(TARGET_NAME) in Info.plist ?